# Link background image disappears between loads

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

```
#nav ul li a.jobs_mn {
    background: url(../images/jobup.png) #2d333e no-repeat 7% 50%;
}

#nav ul li a.jobs_mn:hover {
    background: url(../images/jobover.png) #fff no-repeat 7% 50%;
}
```

And I add the class `jobs_mn` to the link. When I click the link the image disappears until the next page is loading. It's loading a PHP query actualy:

```
<a href="?news=1" class="jobs_mn">bla bla</a>
```

Any idea how to fix this annoying thing?

Comment: Try pre loading your image or using sprite sheets

Comment: Did you mean hred in your a tag or href?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies in the fact that you are changing the background on the `:hover` state. Because the state changes when `:hover` becomes `:click` and the user often will mouseout from the link, you need to ensure you are displaying the same image.

The link essentially has 4 states: before(un-clicked), hover, active, after/clicked.

Add the same `background: url../images/jobover.png) #fff no-repeat 7% 50%` to each state that you want it to be present in. If you want this same image to be present after the link is clicked, it would look like:

```
#nav ul li a.jobs_mn:hover:after {
background: url(../images/jobover.png) #fff no-repeat 7% 50%; }
```

Although it's a bit redundant and a situation I haven't actually run into yet, this should provide a failsafe to keep the image the same after the user has clicked and moved their mouse away while the query is processing.